# Showing data in a table horizontally

Tags: sqlite, pivot

I have a table that stores sensor data (in SQLite) and looks like this;

```
TABLE Timestream:
idTimestream PK autoincrementing integer, 
time int not null, 
value float not null, 
idSensor integer not null FK
```

Some but not all sensors have matching times, but I'll only be considering those that do. What I want to do is rearrange the table into the following format,based on a set of sensors listed in the query, not whole set from the table:

```
Time Sensor1 Sensor2 etc.
```

I was thinking of Creating a temporary table and then inserting time and the first column, then doing a join on the time for subsequent queries, and finally selecting the whole lot. This doesn't sound too efficient though and I was wondering if there was a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to 'pivot' the data, which can be done with multiple case statements:

test data:

> ```
> create table timestream(
>   idTimestream integer primary key autoincrement
> , time int not null
> , value float not null
> , idSensor integer not null);
> ```
>
> ```
> insert into timestream(time, value, idSensor) values(1,0.1,100);
> ```
>
> ```
> insert into timestream(time, value, idSensor) values(1,0.2,101);
> ```
>
> ```
> insert into timestream(time, value, idSensor) values(1,0.3,102);
> ```
>
> ```
> insert into timestream(time, value, idSensor) values(2,0.4,101);
> ```

query:

> ```
> select time, sum(case idSensor when 100 then value end) as s100,
>              sum(case idSensor when 101 then value end) as s101,
>              sum(case idSensor when 102 then value end) as s102
> from timestream
> group by time;
> ```
>
> ```
> time | s100 | s101 | s102
> :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
> 1    | 0.1  | 0.2  | 0.3 
> 2    | null | 0.4  | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=c91d72ae93db28541c67569859d2c437)*

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a [view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).  This will allow you to pull the data you want, in the order you want without having to do a join with a temp table.  One thing to note is i don't believe sqlite will allow you to write to a view, so if you want to do more than just look at the data, you may have to use the view to create a temp table.

Comment: Can you put an `ORDER BY` in a view in SQLite?  I know you can't in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it doesn't, you should be able to use order by when you select the data from the view.

Comment: @JNK: Yes you can: [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/562b1/1)

Comment: ORDER BY should not be allowed in views - what happens if you join two ordered views?  Hence the change in SQL Server to be standardized that a view is just a set definition (like a table) and by definition, all sets are unordered in a RDBMS.